# ¿Cómo aumentar el número de bytes devueltos a las variables PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy realizando una consulta con PDO_ODBC de la siguiente manera:

```
$conexion = new PDO("odbc:".$DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM informacion";
$prep   = $conexion->prepare($sql);   /*PREPARAMOS LA CONSULTA*/
$prep->execute();                           /*EJECUTAMOS LA CONSULTA*/
$result = $prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); /*ALMACENAMOS EL RESULTADO*/
```

En la base de datos solo hay una fila con 3 columnas y una de las columnas almacena esta información:

```
    <div><strong>DOCUMENTOS PARA EL AÑO 2018</strong></div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<ul>
<li><u>DOCUMENTOS NECESARIOS PARA REALIZAR EL TRAMITE:</u></li></ul>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde.</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde.</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde.</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asddeDetrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde.</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<ul>
<li><u>DOCUMENTOS PARA ASDASDASDASD:</u></li></ul>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde.</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asddeDetrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde.</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asddeDetrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde.</div><div>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde<br></div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asddeDetrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asddeDetrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asddeDetrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde.</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div><strong>MAYORES INFORMES</strong></div>
<div>Carrera Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde </div>
<div>Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde</div>
```

cuando realizo la consulta solo me trae el id y el resto de los campos vació, en ODBC normal la solución es configurando `odbc.defaultlrl` que es para definir el tamaño de la variable de respuesta pero no eh encontrado nada referente en PDO.

La base de datos que utilizo es Informix y el servidor es Windows. Cuando realizo la consulta solo por el campo que requiero me aparece el siguiente error:

```
SQLSTATE[SL009]: <<Unknown error>>: 0 [Microsoft][Biblioteca de cursores ODBC] No se enlazaron columnas antes de llamar a SQLFetchScroll o SQLExtendedFetch (SQLFetchScroll[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:559)
```

El mensaje solo aparece cuando consulto solo el campo que almacena la información y cuando la información almacenada en dicho campo es similar a la que puse en el código.

Comment: Haz la prueba si usando la familia [`odbc_*`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.uodbc.php) nativa te soluciona el problema

Comment: Con respecto a como modificar la variable [`odbc.defaultlrl`](http://php.net/manual/es/odbc.configuration.php), prueba usando [`ini_set`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ini-set.php) antes de realizar la consulta, por ejemplo `ini_set('odbc.defaultlrl', '10240'); // 10Kb`

Comment: @aldanux en native odbc me funciona, pero me piden que sea en PDO

Comment: @Marcos asi es como lo tengo configurado pero no funciona, lo tengo al tope 99999999 ya que en el native me funcionó hasta ese punto.

Answer (score 1):

[PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) ofrece como solución para manejar [objetos grandes (LOB)](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.lobs.php) el código del tipo [**PDO::PARAM_LOB**](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.constants.php)

> Grande típicamente significa "alrededor de `4kb` o más", aunque algunas bases de datos pueden manejar fácilmente hasta `32kb` antes de que los datos se consideren "grandes". Los objetos grandes, o `LOB` (acrónimo en inglés de 'Large OBjects'), pueden ser de texto o binarios. `PDO` permite trabajar con este tipo de datos grandes utilizando el código del tipo **PDO::PARAM_LOB** en llamadas a *PDOStatement::bindParam()* o *PDOStatement::bindColumn()*.

### Solución:

Una posible solución a tu problema sería hacer la consulta así:

```
$conexion = new PDO("odbc:".$DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

/* AQUI detallamos las columnas */
$sql    = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM informacion";


$prep   = $conexion->prepare($sql);                    /*PREPARAMOS LA CONSULTA*/
$prep->execute();                                      /*EJECUTAMOS LA CONSULTA*/

/* AQUI bindeamos las columnas a variables y su tipo */
$prep->bindColumn(1, $col1, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
$prep->bindColumn(2, $col2, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$prep->bindColumn(3, $col3, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

/*ALMACENAMOS EL RESULTADO*/
$result = [];
while ($prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {

    $result[] = [
        'col1'=> $col1,
        'col2'=> $col2,
        'col3'=> $col3,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, voy a probarlo y te cuento, tengo una duda, hay forma de hacer la parte del $prep ->bindColum que se aplique a todas las columnas, lo digo en caso de que el select lleve un * .

Comment: Ok no hay problema, esta noche lo pruebo y si todo marcha bn te comento y te asigno la recompensa, va solo PDO::PARAM_LOB sin definir tamaño?.

Comment: Hola, disculpa la demora, estuve algo ocupado, probé la respuesta pero me retorna valor null :/ aunque tu respuesta me dio algo de luz pero no logro que me traiga la información, inclusive si dejo solo la columna que necesito me sigue marcando el mismo error: "No se enlazaron columnas antes de llamar a SQLFetchScroll o SQLExtendedFetch (SQLFetchScroll[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:559) in"

Comment: lo acabo de probar pero sigue sin salir, corrí la sentencia sql en el gestor de base de datos y me marco este error `Error message: [FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]No cast from text to nvarchar` y en php me marca este error: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[]: <<Unknown error>>: 0 (SQLPrepare[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_driver.c:206) in C:\AppServ\www\prueba\PDO\index.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\AppServ\www\prueba\PDO\index.php(12): PDO->prepare('SELECT CAST(edu...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\AppServ\www\prueba\PDO\index.php on line 12`.

Comment: @Andrés, estas usando una DB de `Informix`, intenta establecer la conexción así `$conexion = new PDO("informix:".$DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);`. [Mas info aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-informix.connection.php)

Comment: Es que no tengo el driver Informix instalado, estuve buscándolo en `PECL`  el [dll](https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_INFORMIX/1.3.1/windows) pero solo esta para las versiones de `PHP 5.3` y `5.4` y la versión del servidor en el que trabajo es la `7.1` sobre windows server por eso es que estoy trabajando con `ODBC`.

Comment: A partir de la versión [`1.3.2`](https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=PDO_INFORMIX&release=1.3.3) es compatible con `PHP v7+`. Puedes descargar una [`dll para PHP7.1 vc14 x86 aquí`](https://github.com/stephane303/php_pdo_informix-1.3.3-7.1-vc14-x86)

Comment: Voy a probarlo y te cuento.

Comment: Primero Gracias por la Dll, estuve un buen de tiempo buscando y buscando y no la encontraba ya conecto directamente con PDO_INFORMIX, pero me pasa algo curioso cuando realizo la consulta, me devuelve el arreglo esto `array(6) { [0]=> array(1) { ["info"]=> resource(2) of type (stream) } [1]=> array(1) { ["info"]=> resource(3) of type (stream) } [2]=> array(1) { ["info"]=> resource(4) of type (stream) } [3]=> array(1) { ["info"]=> resource(5) of type (stream) }  } ` estoy tratando de extraer la información  con `stream_get_contents` pero no me resulto.

Comment: @Andrés, creo que este nuevo escenario merece una nueva pregunta ya que, si bien esta relacionado, la solución no es la misma que para el de la pregunta actual.

Comment: voy a seguir revisando si al final no doy, armare la pregunta, espero puedas participar.

Comment: [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/127461/resource2-of-type-stream-pdo-informix) te dejo la publicación de la pregunta.