# ¿Como leer resource(2) of type (stream) con PDO_INFORMIX?

Tags: php, pdo, informix

Tengo un problema con el retorno de la información que realizo con `PDO_INFORMIX`, a continuación les muestro mi caso:

**1. Base de Datos:**

`INFORMIX`

**2. Schema:**

**-Tabla:** `cartas`

**-Campos:**

```
|id      | codigo | titulo     |contenido   |
---------------------------------------------
| SERIAL | INTEGER|VARCHAR(15) | TEXT       |
```

**3. Contenido de la tabla:**

**-id:** `1`
**-codigo :** `25463985`
**-titulo :** `Requisitos Especiales`

**-contenido:**

```
<div><strong>DOCUMENTOS PARA EL AÑO 2018</strong></div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<ul>
<li><u>DOCUMENTOS NECESARIOS PARA REALIZAR EL TRAMITE:</u></li></ul>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde.</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde.</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde.</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asddeDetrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde.</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<ul>
<li><u>DOCUMENTOS PARA ASDASDASDASD:</u></li></ul>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde.</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asddeDetrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde.</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asddeDetrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde.</div><div>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde<br></div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asddeDetrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asddeDetrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asddeDetrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; *Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde.</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div><strong>MAYORES INFORMES</strong></div>
<div>Carrera Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde </div>
<div>Detrffghfjh Fasdasdasd as Iasdasdasdasd asdde</div>
```

Estoy realizando la conexión a la Base de Datos por medio de `PDO_INFORMIX` de la siguiente manera:

**CONEXIÓN:**

```
$conexion = new PDO("informix:host=127.0.0.1;service=sqldesarrol;database=bdtest; server=online_shm;protocol=onsoctcp;EnableScrollableCursors=1;", "userTest", "PassTest");
$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

**CONSULTA:**

```
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM cartas";
$prep   = $conexion->prepare($sql);   
$prep->execute();                   
$result = $prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
```

Realizo un `var_dump` para ver la información retornada y tengo el siguiente resultado.

**RESULTADO:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["CODIGO"]=>
    string(8) "25463985"
    ["TITULO"]=>
    string(21) "Requisitos Especiales"
    ["CONTENIDO"]=>
    resource(2) of type (stream)

  }
}
```

No entiendo porque me retorna el contenido del campo contenido de esa manera.

**QUE E PROBADO:**

```
if(is_resource($result[0]['CONTENIDO']))
{
    echo get_resource_type($result[0]['CONTENIDO']);
}
```

**Retorna:** `stream`

En base a esa prueba e utilizado la funcion `get_resources` pero me da el siguiente error:

`<b>Warning</b>:  get_resources() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in <b>C:\....`

Lo que mas me da curiosidad es que si hago lo siguiente:

`echo $result[0]['EDUFORCONTEX'];`

Me da como resultado:
`Resource id #2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta hacerlo así:

```
$conexion = new PDO("informix:host=127.0.0.1;service=sqldesarrol;database=bdtest; server=online_shm;protocol=onsoctcp;EnableScrollableCursors=1;", "userTest", "PassTest");
$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql    = "SELECT id, codigo, titulo, contenido FROM cartas";
$prep   = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$prep->execute();

/* AQUI bindeamos las columnas a variables y su tipo */
$prep->bindColumn(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$prep->bindColumn(2, $codigo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prep->bindColumn(3, $titulo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prep->bindColumn(4, $resource, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

/*ALMACENAMOS EL RESULTADO*/
$result = [];
while ($prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {

    $result[] = [
        'id'=> $id,
        'codigo'=> $codigo,
        'titulo'=> $titulo,
        'contenido'=> stream_get_contents($resource),
    ];
}
```

Comment: Sos un Crack Amigo, funciono perfectamente.